# Claims in IHttpContextAccessor are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect

in my .net core mvc application I try to get the user claims in my user service. but the claims list is empty.

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    }
    public string UserId { get; }
}
```

[image: Service]

but in the page there are claims. What is the difference?

[image: Page]

**ConfigureServices:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<EmailOptions>(options =>
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("Email").Bind(options);
        });
        services.AddPingIdentity(Configuration);
        services.AddApplication();
        services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);

        services.AddConfiguredRazorPages();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: it depends on where and how are you calling your service, is it through a webrequest?

Comment: I am injecting the service into the ApplicationDbContext and in a mediator command. In both cases there are no claims

Comment: your information isn't enogth, may be you call app.UseAuthentication after UseMvc

Comment: I have added a screenshot with my Configure Method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `CurrentUserService` is instantiated by the dependency injection framework before the Authentication middleware has set the claims of `HttpContext.User`. As the `HttpContext.User` is accessed (using the `IhttpContextAccessor`) in the constructor of the `CurrentUserService`, the claims are not yet available.

A potential solution is to access the `HttpContext.User` property when accessing the `UserId` property of `ICurrentUserService`.

```
public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public string UserId => httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the explanation Gaste that worked like a charm in my situation. I didnt realize the order of operations.

Comment: I have a similar issue but when I debug the `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims` it has no values, but I can see twhen OpenIdConnect authenticates the user there are claims.